# Spiral running by time

Tags: haskell

This is a question I have some difficulty making, but I will try to explain the best i can.

Imagine this is the coordenates of a square table

> ```
> (0,0) (1,0) (2,0) (3,0) (4,0)
>
> (0,1) (1,1) (2,1) (3,1) (4,1)
>
> (0,2) (1,2) (2,2) (3,2) (4,2)
>
> (0,3) (1,3) (2,3) (3,3) (4,3)
>
> (0,4) (1,4) (2,4) (3,4) (4,4)
> ```

Now I have 2 Ints

> d = dimension of the square table
>
> t=>0 and t<= d^2

and i need to find a way to calculate the coordenates i will fill in moment t, and i need to fill it in a spiral, like this examples:

> ```
> t=(n^2) -> (0,0)
>
> t=(n^2)-1 -> (1,0)
>
> ...
>
> t=((n^2)-n)+1 -> (4,0)
>
> t=((n^2)-n) -> (4,1)
>
> t=((n^2)-n)-1 -> (4,2)
>
> ...
>
>
> t=0 -> (2,2)
> ```

So What I'm trying to explain is i need to acces the table in the order:

```
(0,0) > (1,0) > (2,0) > (3,0) > (4,0) > (4,1) > ... > (4,4) > (3,4) > ... > (0,4) > (0,3) > (0,2) > (0,1) > (1,1) > (2,1) > (3,1) > (3,2) > (3,3) > (2,3) > (1,3) > (1,2) > (2,2)
```

Can someone give some advice on how to build a function, using only the `t=moment` and `d=dimension`, that calculate the `coordenate(column,line)` I need to edit?

Sorry for English errors and confusing question.

Thanks for all help

Comment: what have you tried - where are you stuck, can you create the square, do you know how to handle lists and lists of lists? how familiar are you with haskell?

Comment: Yes i have the square, and all functions to handle in the program. I only miss a function that returns a tuple of type (Int,Int) = (column,line), that tells me the posiction i will be editting in that moment (time)

Comment: I have the done a program of a game, and that game, at the time d^2 starts closing the map, ending at the time 1(editing the center square of the map) at time d^2 i want to edit the square (0,0). Do you understand what i'm trying to do?

Comment: In relation to how familiar I am with haskell, i started a few weaks ago, this is the first 'big' project I do, and I only miss this function(I even have how to access the map and what to do after i find the tuple (colum,line). So i only miss this function that finds the tuple. So I'm not an expert or anything close to that. Thank you

Comment: I already solved it, I 'inverted' the time making it (t-(d^2)+1) and it became much easier. Thanks anyway

Comment: if you have solved it - don't hesitate to add your solution

Comment: I didn't added but i should, now epsilonhalbe added a diferrent soluction then mine, more advanged actually than what i had, with same result. Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module Spiral where

import Data.List (transpose)

type Time = Int
type Dimension = Int
type Coordinate = (Int,Int)

spiral :: Dimension -> [Coordinate]
spiral d | d <= 0    = error "Dimension must be a positive number."
         | otherwise = let square = [[(x,y)|x <- [0..(d-1)]]|y <- [0..(d-1)]]
                           rotate = reverse . transpose
                           spiral' :: [[a]] -> [a]
                           spiral' []     = []
                           spiral' (x:xs) = spiral' (rotate xs) ++ reverse x
                        in spiral' square

spiralTime :: Dimension -> Time -> Coordinate
spiralTime d t | 0 <= t && t < d*d = spiral d !! t
               | otherwise         = error $ "Time must be in [0,"++show (d*d)++")"
```

Note that this function then can be used as `getCoordinateAtTime` to get a function as you described.

```
$> ghci stover.hs
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/epsilonhalbe/.ghc/ghci.conf
[1 of 1] Compiling Spiral           ( stover.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Spiral.
*Spiral> spiral (-1)
*** Exception: Dimension must be a positive number.
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at stover.hs:10:24 in main:Spiral
*Spiral> spiralTime 5 25
*** Exception: Time must be in [0,25)
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at stover.hs:20:38 in main:Spiral
*Spiral> let getCoordinateAtTime = spiralTime 5
*Spiral> getCoordinateAtTime 0
(2,2)
*Spiral> getCoordinateAtTime 24
(0,0)
*Spiral> getCoordinateAtTime 11
(0,3)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed, I had this done but in a different way, this soluction has more advanced functions than mine.

Comment: please show your solution as well! It is always interesting to compare!

Comment: Done, I think your soluction is more advanced then mine. Thank you, but anyway can you reply what you think of mine?